An inequality problem from secrets in inequality using AM-GM.
If \begin{align} a_1, a_2, a_3...a_n \space are \space positive \space real \space numbers. \end{align}
and
\begin{align} a_i \in (0,i] \end{align}
prove that
\begin{align} 2^n \cdot a_{1} \cdot (a_{1} + a_{2}) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + \ldots + a_{n}) \geq (n+1) \cdot a_{1}^{2} \cdot a_{2}^{2} \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n}^{2} \end{align}
This is a problem from a book i am doing called secrets in inequalities by pham kim hung. This problem is supposed to be solved using only the AM-GM inequality.I am not able to make any progress, any help will be appreciated.

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h537718p3090155
